# Exploiting uniform syntax of value types and references

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns

Let's say we have the following `Base` class, and two derived classes `Derived1` and `Derived2`:

```
class Base {
// Some declarations ...
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
// Some declarations ...
public:
  vector<int> _array;
};

class Derived2 : public Base {
// Some declarations ...
public:
  vector<int> &_array;
};
```

That is, we have a common class but the underlying data structures are of different types.

Say that we want to access individual elements of the underlying arrays using a uniform interface from a `Base` pointer. i.e. something like this:

```
Base *bPtr = new Derived1(...);
int val = bPtr->index(3);
```

Having a pure virtual function called `index` in `Base` is one solution. However, in that case we would need the same `int index(uint x) { return _array[x]; }`  implementation in both of the derived classes. This is ugly, and we cannot implement that function in `Base` since it does not know about `_array`.

So we must either (1) change the types of `_array`s to the same type (say, to a `vector<int>*`) and have the implementation of `index` in `Base` or (2) have two implementations in `Derived1` and `Derived` in order to make use of a common interface. However I cannot afford (1) since it would add an extra indirection layer to `Derived1`, and I want to avoid that if possible. Having a number of member variables like that makes (2) horrible since that is a lot of boilerplate and replication, and hard to maintain.

**I understand that the two `index` functions are actually different functions**, since they operate on different types. In many other scenarios `Derived1` and `Derived2` would need separate functions since they have different behaviour (and would be compiled to different object codes). However in the case of C++ the implementations are syntactically similar, so I'm wondering whether there is a way to exploit that.

One possible solution is having a free function:

```
template <class T>
int index(const T &obj, uint x) {
  return obj._array[x];
}
```

where we declare `index` a friend of both `Derived1` and `Derived2`. However, this might not be considered elegant since it uses a friend declaration (also declaring friend twice is repetitive).

Hence, my question is:
Is there a more elegant way to implement `index`, while avoiding performance costs and code repetition?

**Addendum**:
CRTP is very close to what I want, but it introduces two new types (`Base<Derived1>` is the first, and `Base<Derived2>` is the second) while deleting the existing type `Base`. Such a refactoring would trigger many more changes in the codebase, which is not desirable (such as making functions/classes which utilize `Base` template functions/classes, or even moving them from headers to source files). What I want ideally wouldn't require making changes to the rest of the codebase.

Comment: Can I say you are looking for some *design patterns*? Because there is a tag [design-patterns] for that.

Comment: This could be a good fit for the [curiously-recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) in the class `Base`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

```
template <typename D, typename B = Base>
class CrtpBase : public B
{
    public:
    int index(size_t ind){return static_cast<D*>(this)->_array[ind];}
};

struct Derived1 : public CrtpBase<Derived1>
{
    vector<int> _array = {1,2,3};
};

struct Derived2 : public CrtpBase<Derived2>
{
    vector<int> _arr = {4,5,6};
    vector<int>& _array = _arr;
};
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ba8757d8c17e0f3).

Comment: Thanks! However this completely removes `Base`, but what I want is just the change of the implementation of the existing API (added a bit more explanation to the question).

Comment: @loudandclear How about the edited change? You still get to keep `Base`. `CrtpBase` simply lets you add this functionality to the `Derived`s.

Comment: Oh, I see, something's missing though. I think CrtpBase is supposed to derive from B, then it makes sense. Is that right?